# equal in if statement not working as expected

Tags: perl

```
use Text::Diff;
my $count;
our $stats2 = 0;
for($count = 0; $count <= 1000; $count++){
    my $data_dir="archive/oswiostat/oracleapps.*dat";
    my $data_file= `ls -t $data_dir | head -1`;
    chomp($data_file);
    while(defined($data_file)){
        print $data_file;
        open (DAT,$data_file) || die("Could not open file! $!");
        my @stats1 = stat $data_file;
        my @raw_data=<DAT>;
        close(DAT);
        print "Stats1 is :$stats1[9]\n";
        sleep(5);
        print "Checking $stats1[9] equals $stats2\n";
        if(chomp($stats1[9]) != chomp($stats2)){
            print "I am here";
            my @diff = diff \@raw_data, $data_file, { STYLE => "Context" };
            print @diff || die ("Didn't see any updates $!");
        }
        $stats2 = $stats1[9];
        print "Stat2: $stats2\n";
    }
}
```

Output

```
[oracle@oracleapps osw]$ perl client_socket1.pl
archive/oswiostat/oracleapps.localdomain_iostat_12.06.28.1900.datStats1 is :1340925244
Checking 1340925244 equals 0
Stat2: 1340925244
archive/oswiostat/oracleapps.localdomain_iostat_12.06.28.1900.datStats1 is :1340925298
Checking 1340925298 equals 1340925244
Stat2: 1340925298
archive/oswiostat/oracleapps.localdomain_iostat_12.06.28.1900.datStats1 is :1340925304
Checking 1340925304 equals 1340925298
Stat2: 1340925304
archive/oswiostat/oracleapps.localdomain_iostat_12.06.28.1900.datStats1 is :1340925304
Checking 1340925304 equals 1340925304
Stat2: 1340925304
archive/oswiostat/oracleapps.localdomain_iostat_12.06.28.1900.datStats1 is :1340925304
```

As show in the output when @stats1[9] is not equal to $stats2 it should go into the if loop and print "I am here" but it is not working that way. Can you please identify the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`chomp()` modifies a string as a side-effect and returns the linefeed it deleted from a string, not the modified string. You likely want to write

```
chomp $stats1[9];
chomp $stats2;
if($stats1[9] != $stats2) {
```

Comment: thanks for the help it is working now. so what would be the output for chomp(23232/n) would be then?

Comment: Your description of `chomp`s return value is wrong: *It returns the
total number of characters removed from all its arguments.*

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem:

```
if (chomp($stats1[9]) != chomp($stats2)) {
```

should be

```
chomp($stats1[9]);
chomp($stats2);
if ($stats1[9] != $stats2) {
```

and also

```
my @diff = diff \@raw_data, $data_file, { STYLE => "Context" }; 
print @diff || die ("Didn't see any updates $!");
```

should be

```
my $diff = diff \@raw_data, $data_file, { STYLE => "Context" }; 
print $diff || die ("Didn't see any updates $!");
```

Comment: @Omega also my diff is not working can you help me with it too.

Comment: VeeraMarni - I corrected my first response regarding `chomp` and compare and I also added section regarding `dif`